# Как открывать layout файлы в BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Как с помощью `BottomNavigationView` реализовать открытие определенных layout xml?
Вот код, который реализует вывод текста, а как реализовать открытие layout'?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textFavorites;
    private TextView textCollection;
    private TextView textFriends;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textFavorites = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_favorites);
        textCollection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_collection);
        textFriends = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_friends);

        BottomNavigationView bnv = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bnv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(getBottomNavigationListener());
    }

    @NonNull
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener getBottomNavigationListener() {
        return new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorite:
                        textFavorites.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textCollection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textFriends.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;

                    case R.id.action_collection:
                        textFavorites.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textCollection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textFriends.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;

                    case R.id.action_friends:
                        textFavorites.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textCollection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textFriends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;

import android.app.Fragment;

import android.view.MenuItem;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




        BottomNavigationView bnv = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bnv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(getBottomNavigationListener());
    }

    @NonNull
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener getBottomNavigationListener() {
        return new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_zametki:
                        changeFragment(R.layout.main);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.action_spisok:
                        changeFragment(R.layout.spisok_activity);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.action_cal:
                        changeFragment(R.layout.cal_activity);
                }
                return false;
            }

            public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment) // id  FrameLayout
                        .commit();
            }

            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду Intent?

Comment: Зачем Вам это нужно? В этой ситуации лучше использовать фрагменты.

Comment: Через intent заработало. А как через фрагменты? Создать FrameLayout на главном экране и прописать его в главном Activity? И в чем преимущество?

Comment: FrameLayout и NavigatonBar лежат в активити, на основании выбраной вкладки из навигейшна сетите в фрейм лейаут нужный фрагмент. Intent нужен для других целей.